# How to send html table as body and excel as attachment using mailx or sendmail in solaris

Tags: shell, unix, sendmail, solaris, mailx

I am generating the executive summary in form of html and the complete data in csv. How to send the html table as body of a mail and the csv as attachment of the same.

Answer (score 1):

if you have an option to to use mutt client you can try:

```
echo "html message" | mutt -a "/tmp/file.csv" -s "subject" -- recipient@example.com
```